# Why would yesterday"s steps increase after getting today's steps?

Tags: microsoft-band

When using the Microsoft Health API, why would I get say 1910 steps for yesterday and 164 steps for today, however, later today, I'll get 1972 steps for yesterday on a later sync.  Does that seem normal?  How does one know that the number for yesterday is "final"?  Thanks!

Eric